# Replacing loop with vectorization for sequential operations in R

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

I'm trying to use the tidyverse to avoid using a loop in my simulation. I have a dataset with 4 key variables. They're all interdependent, and each calculation needs to be handled row by row sequentially. Let's take this small sample to illustrate my issue:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(var_1 = c(250,190,120,150),
       var_2 = c(200,NA,NA,NA),
       var_3 = c(100,NA,NA,NA),
       var_4 = c(1,NA,NA,NA))
```

var_3 is essentially an inventory proxy. I need to evaluate var_1 w.r. to var_2 to determine if there's a change. If there is a change, var_3 decreases by one unit, and then var_4 changes as well. In each subsequent step, the calculation of var_2 depends on var_4.

This is an example of the type of calculation I need done. It works fine in a loop:

```r
for (i in 2:4) {
  df$var_3[i] <- case_when(lag(df$var_1)[i] >= lag(df$var_2)[i] ~ lag(df$var_3)[i] - 1,
                           TRUE ~ lag(df$var_3)[i])
  df$var_4[i] <- case_when(df$var_3[i] < lag(df$var_3)[i] ~ lag(df$var_4)[i] - 0.1,
                           TRUE ~ lag(df$var_4)[i])
  df$var_2[i] <- lag(df$var_2)[i] * df$var_4[i]
  }
```

Running the above code yields:

```r
# A tibble: 4 × 4
  var_1 var_2 var_3 var_4
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1   250  200    100   1  
2   190  180     99   0.9
3   120  144     98   0.8
4   150  115.    98   0.8
```

In the loop I essentially compare the value in line n-1 to obtain values in line n, and so on and so forth. The main problems I had running the with, say,`purrr` is that it does not seem to run operations sequentially, which is necessary. I didn't manage to get var_3 to decrease, even if I invent values for the other dependent variables.

Do you have any idea how this example can be consolidated in the tidyverse?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use loop since each row depending on the previous calculations on the above row but you can use this function

```
fNext <- function(df , i) {
    if(df$var_1[i] >= df$var_2[i]) df$var_3[i+1] <- df$var_3[i] - 1 
    else {df$var_3[i+1] <- df$var_3[i]}
    if(df$var_3[i+1] < df$var_3[i]) df$var_4[i+1] <- df$var_4[i] - .1
    else {df$var_4[i+1] <- df$var_4[i]}
    df$var_2[i+1] <- df$var_2[i] * df$var_4[i+1]
    df
}
```

Then apply for

```
for(i in 1:(nrow(df)-1)){
    df <- fNext(df ,i)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the proposition. It's an interesting way to put the loop inside a function. However, since I only use the loop twice, and it's not exactly the same time it doesn't really make my code more concise. 
I was really curious to know if their was another way than a loop.